# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed (mysql, java)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I was stuck with the error , here my line number 42 is `while(rs.next()){`, please help me with this i am stuck at this for few hrs.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:740)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6326)
    at removeStopwords.RemoveStopwords.main(RemoveStopwords.java:42)
```

This is my code:

```
package removeStopwords;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class RemoveStopwords {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbv2";

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;
        ResultSet rs3 = null;
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = null;
        int event_id = 10;
        sql = "SELECT id,text from tweet where event_id = " + event_id;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        String text = "";
        Long id;
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getLong("id");
            text = rs.getString("text");
            System.out.println("tweet = " + text);
            text = text.replaceAll("http[^\\s]+", "");
            text = text.replaceAll("www[^\\s]+", "");
            System.out.println("tweet after removal of links= " + text);

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String stopword = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println("stopword : " + stopword);

                sql = "SELECT * from stopwords WHERE word =" + '"'+stopword+'"';
                rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if (rs2.next()) {
                    text = text.replaceAll(stopword, "");
                    System.out.println("tweet after removing stopword = " + text);
                }
                sql = "SELECT * from filtertweet where tweet_id = " + id + "";
                rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if (!rs3.next()) {
                    sql = "INSERT INTO filtertweet VALUES(?,?)";
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setLong(1, id);
                    ps.setString(2, text);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }

            }
        }
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Statement` object can have only one active `ResultSet`, so when you execute `rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql)`, the first ResultSet (`rs`) gets closed.

Create two `Statement` objects, one for `rs` and another for `rs2`.

Quoting the javadoc of [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.

Answer (score 1):

One ResultSet for one Statement is valid. When you are executing multiple queries use various Statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

    stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    String sql;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;
    ResultSet rs3 = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int event_id = 10;
    sql = "SELECT id,text from tweet where event_id = " + event_id;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    String text = "";
    Long id;
    while (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getLong("id");
        text = rs.getString("text");
        System.out.println("tweet = " + text);
        text = text.replaceAll("http[^\\s]+", "");
        text = text.replaceAll("www[^\\s]+", "");
        System.out.println("tweet after removal of links= " + text);

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String stopword = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println("stopword : " + stopword);

            sql = "SELECT * from stopwords WHERE word =" + '"'+stopword+'"';

            Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
            rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql);
            if (rs2.next()) {
                text = text.replaceAll(stopword, "");
                System.out.println("tweet after removing stopword = " + text);
            }
            sql = "SELECT * from filtertweet where tweet_id = " + id + "";

            Statement stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
            rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql);
            if (!rs3.next()) {
                sql = "INSERT INTO filtertweet VALUES(?,?)";
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setLong(1, id);
                ps.setString(2, text);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }

        }
    }
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC does not allow you to close the Statement that created the ResultSet or to execute another query that creates a ResultSet using the same Statement. Create different Statement objects and Resultset objects, make sure to not use the same Statement objects to execute two different Resultset statements.