# How to make my SQL Database update itself everyday?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, sql-update

I tried to make my SQL Database update itself everyday in java. But, when i tried it, an exception happen that said "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"
How do i make it work?

```
 public void loadData(){
    model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    long Test = 0;
    String tanggalInsert = null;
    String TanggalDatang = null;
    float hasil = 0, berat, etmal;
    long Waktu;
    Date TglDatang;
    Date TglToday;

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pembayaran","root","");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM pembayaran.transaksi";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){   
            TanggalDatang = rs.getString("kedatangan");
            SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            TglDatang = (Date) date.parse(TanggalDatang);
            TglToday = new Date();
            Waktu = Math.abs(TglToday.getTime() - TglDatang.getTime());
            Test = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Waktu);
            berat = Float.valueOf(rs.getString("berat"));
            etmal = Float.valueOf(Test)/15;
            hasil = berat*etmal*370;
            statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE `pembayaran`.`transaksi` SET `hari` = '"+Test+"', `harga` = '"+hasil+"' WHERE `transaksi`.`id_transaksi` ="+rs.getString("id_transaksi"));
            Object[] o = new Object[6];
            o[0]=rs.getString("id_transaksi");
            o[1]=rs.getString("nama_kapal");
            o[2]=rs.getString("berat");
            String a = rs.getString("kedatangan");
            String b = a.substring(8, 10)+"/"+a.substring(5, 7)+"/"+a.substring(0, 4);
            o[3]=b;
            o[4]=rs.getString("hari");
            o[5]=rs.getString("harga");
            model.addRow(o);
        }
       rs.close();
       statement.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Kerusakan = " +e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "update itself everyday?" You mean you want to run your update statement once per day? Are you running your loadData method in a loop which checks the time periodically?

Comment: where is the exception coming from? it doesn't seem to be thrown from the posted code

Comment: Probably from trying to read from `rs` after `executeUpdate()` is invoked **on the same Statement**. Try reading all the attributes from `rs` before calling `executeUpdate()`, or use a different Statement instance to invoke `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: the statement is also vulnerable to SQL injection. should use bind variables

Comment: Change your while loop to a for loop and try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed (mysql, java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671535/operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed-mysql-java)

Comment: Yes, i want to update my database whenever i open my program. The exception comming from executeUpdate()

Comment: I ever try what Andrew said and another exception appear

Comment: For loop don't fix my problem and my ResultSet is only one

Comment: use a different statement for the update

Comment: What statement i should use?

Answer (score 1):

You have these statements:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE `pembayaran`.`transaksi` SET `hari` = '"+Test+"', `harga` = '"+hasil+"' WHERE `transaksi`.`id_transaksi` ="+rs.getString("id_transaksi"));
o[0]=rs.getString("id_transaksi");
```

Calling `executeUpdate` closes the `ResultSet` so you can't call `rs.getString` after it.

Instead, create a separate statement to run the update, with `con.createStatement()`.

Comment: This is fixed my problem
Thanks :3